# SP Master page changes not reflecting in page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

I created a custom master page with following addition

```
<meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=10”/>
```

I need it for my jqplot to work in SharePoint 2010.

When I save the file, my changes are not reflected in the code when I open it in developer tool.  The xua still shows "IE=8" and my charts still don't show.

What is the proper way to publish a master page in SharePoint 2010 foundation

Comment: Just noticed, you have foundation.

Comment: Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint designer, first ensure the master page file is published (and approved) as a major version and right click your custom master page and set it to be the default master page and custom master page.

Comment: I want to apply it to just 1 page though.  I don't want it to affect the rest of the pages in my site.  Also, how do I ensure that my custom master page is published?  I've been having a hard time with that.

Comment: Using SharePoint designer, check the "version" attribute on your masterpage file. It has to be a major version (ex: 2.0) for it to be published. It it is not, it will only be a problem for your users, not for you, so be sure to always check with another user account if you can still see your changes. Secondly, to apply the masterpage to a single page only, not the whole site, just change the MasterUrl attribute on the page, from "~masterurl/default.master", to the url of your custom masterpage, like "~sitecollection/_catalogs/[...].master" or a hardcoded path.